# sklearn always predicts 1 when trying to predict digits

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, blender, scikits

I'm trying to write code that predicts digits from curves in blender.
so I converted the curves to matrices like the ones sklearn use and tried to predict the number, unfortunately, no matter what I do the prediction is always 1.

the 2d matrix (it looks like the circle that I have in blender):

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  25.  25.   0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.  25.  25.  25.   0.  25.  25.   0.]
 [  0.  25.   0.   0.   0.   0.  25.   0.]
 [  0.  25.   0.   0.   0.   0.  25.   0.]
 [  0.  25.   0.   0.   0.   0.  25.   0.]
 [  0.   0.  25.  25.  25.  25.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

the code:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
import scipy.misc

ob = bpy.context.object
assert ob.type == 'CURVE' # throw error if it's not a curve
curve = ob.data
spline = curve.splines.active # let's assume there's only one
assert spline.type == 'BEZIER' # throw error if it's not a bezier

shortest = None
shortestDist = 10000
shortest_x = None
shortestDist_x = 10000
result = []
for point in spline.bezier_points:
    dist = point.co.y
    dist_x = point.co.x
    if dist < shortestDist : #test if better so far
        shortest = point
        shortestDist = dist   
    if dist_x < shortestDist_x : #test if better so far
        shortest_x = point
        shortestDist_x = dist  

print(1 / abs(shortest.co.y))
result.append([shortest, shortestDist, dist, dist_x])
mult_y = 1 / abs(shortest.co.y)
mult_x = 1 / abs(shortest_x.co.x)
point_pos = []
for point in spline.bezier_points:
    loc = point.co.y
    loc_x = point.co.x
    max_y = loc * mult_y
    max_x = loc_x * mult_x
    point_pos.append([loc, loc_x])

matrix = np.zeros((8, 8))
pixel = []

for index in enumerate(matrix):
    matrix_to_co_y = 1 / len(matrix) * index[0]
    for index_y in enumerate(matrix[index[0]]):
        matrix_to_co_x = 1 / len(matrix) * index_y[0]
        #print(matrix_to_co_y)
        for point in point_pos:
            if matrix_to_co_y > point[0] > matrix_to_co_y - 1 / len(matrix):
                if matrix_to_co_x > point[1] > matrix_to_co_x - 1 / len(matrix):
                    pixel.append([index[0], index_y[0]])

for p in enumerate(pixel):
    matrix[p[1][0]][p[1][1]] = 25

flat = np.ravel(matrix)


digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)

x,y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1]
clf.fit(x,y)
print('Prediction:',clf.predict([flat]))

print(matrix)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at the scikit-learn tutorial. There, they show the classification of handwritten digits. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#introduction 

If you can get your input into the same format as the Digits dataset, you should be able to follow the tutorial point-for-point

Comment: @KPLauritzen I tried that, the matrix looks identical to the ones from the training data

Comment: What happens if you try to to predict on some of the inputs from the `digits` dataset? Also, could you try to use `np.reshape` or `np.flatten` instead of `np.ravel`. I think you are getting a flat vector from columns instead of rows from the image matrix

Comment: @KPLauritzen the digits from the dataset work perfectly and my array is in the exact same format as the digits but it only ever returns 1 :(

Answer (score 0):

This could either be a problem with your input image or with the classifier. 
To test where the problem is you could

1) Try using more than one input image. Try making one image for each digit, 0-9. If your classifier predicts "1" for all of them, the problem is probably in the classifier. But if it can predict some of them, then it was likely just your single input image that caused trouble.

2) Try using a different classifier. Almost anything can give you decent performance on the `digits` dataset. I tried with `RandomForestClassifier`, and it correctly predicts your image as "0".

Proof of concept:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import datasets
my_input = np.array(
 [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
 [  0.,   0.,   0.,  25.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
 [  0.,  25.,  25.,  25.,   0.,  25.,  25.,   0.],
 [  0.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  25.,   0.],
 [  0.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  25.,   0.],
 [  0.,  25.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  25.,   0.],
 [  0.,   0.,  25.,  25.,  25.,  25.,   0.,   0.],
 [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
iris = datasets.load_iris()
digits = datasets.load_digits()
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(digits.data, digits.target)
clf.predict(my_input.reshape(1, -1))
# Outputs array([0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should verify if the predicted probabilities are higher than the default threshold. If it is the case, you will find always 1 as the class predicted. To verify the values of the probabilities, you may run the following code, since your test features are idenfied in your code as: flat.

```
clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100) # This line of code is from your post
x,y = digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1] # This line of code is from your post
clf.fit(x,y)  # This line of code is from your post
y_pred=svc.predict_proba(flat) # Here, I predict the probabilities, using the test data you have named flat.

# The predicted probabilities are printed bellow
print(y_pred)
```

Sure, you have taken a glance at the values of the predicted probabilities, `y_pred`, printed with the code above. If all these probabilities are higher than 0.5, which is the default threshold for binary classification, you should used the code below, and change the threshold to a value higher than the minimum value of the probabilities predicted above. For example, suppose that the minimum value of the probabilities is 0.55, the threshold should be higher than 0.55. I choose 0.6. However, if 0.6 is higher than the maximum value of the probability,

```
threshold=0.6    
ypred=(y_pred[:,1]>threshold).astype('int') 
print(ypred)
```

You can try several value for the threshold and test which one produce the best metric (accuracy score, recall, precision etc.) you are interested.